# How to add option that User to select a location to install in .Net Setup Project while installing setup?

Tags: asp.net, setup-project

I have added Setup Project in my web Application for the user to host my project in their Machine in IIS...

While installing my setup it default installed in C: Drive, not able to change the drive location while installing...

How to Achieve this?

I need user to select the drive location where to install the setup while installing..

Using Visual Studio 2010.

Problem: Actually My Setup will Host my application in the IIS after installing it. during installation while clicking on 'Disk Cost' button,not able to choose the drives shown in the window, it taking default C drive...

Note: 'Default Location' property also not in the File System -> Web Application Folder Property Window.

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS - Creation of your own new Application Pool & Web Site and Configure that with Physical path of your own (Other than C Drive) - Select the Newly created Application Pool while installing your Web Setup then it will install in path you mentioned while creating your website in IIS. Note: Give Different Port while creating New Web Site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Case of Winforms deplyment:

Right click on the deployment project in the Solution window and select View, File System.
Click on the Application Folder. Notice in the Properties window, change the Default location to whatever you want

Case of Web:

You can implement this by overriding the “Install” method, check this for an example [Allow user to set physical directory path during Web Project deployment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16416/Allow-user-to-set-physical-directory-path-during-W)

Comment: DefaultLocation property of the Application Folder not there in Property window, is it Web Application Folder?

Comment: Actually My Setup will Host my application in the IIS after installing it. during installation while clicking on 'Disk Cost' not able to choose the drives shown in the window...

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16416/Allow-user-to-set-physical-directory-path-during-W